# BASH Delete type of file thats not listed within a html file

Tags: bash

Fairly new to BASH and seeking some advice as im struggling with even getting started on this.

I have a web page that lists a load of images, like so

```
<img src="01.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1080" />
<img src="02.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1080" />
<img src="03.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1080" />
```

I would like to run BASH to read this web page, its local, pick up the file names, i.e. 01.jpg, 02.jpg and 03.jpg and then delete all other .jpg files in the directory that don't match. So for example if the folder had 04.jpg as well then this file would be deleted as it is not in the web page.

Sorry I haven't posted any coding, just not getting my head around this one at all.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want a fully written script or the general direction to go in w/ BASH functions?  People catch a lot of guff for treating this like a code service, just an FYI

Comment: Bash only? It is more robust in a language that has an HTML parser (Perl, Ruby, Python for example)

Comment: An easier way to do something like this is to move all the files named in the file to a new directory. Then delete the files that remain in the original directory.

Comment: Hi, no I wasn't using this as a code service, just wanted some pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using [Python](https://www.python.org) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (a robust HTML parser module for Python):

```
python -c '
import sys, glob, bs4;
print("\n".join(
    set(glob.glob("*.jpg")) -
    set(e["src"] for e in bs4.BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read()).find_all("img"))
))' < file.htm | xargs rm`
```

A few comments: it prints the *set difference* between the jpg files in current directory and the filenames found in the `<img src="..">` tags, one item per line

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Never heard of BeautifulSoup before and works like a charm. I'll be using BeautifulSoup for other things now that im aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec bash -c \
    'f="{}"; f=${f#./}; if ! grep -wq "img src=\"$f\"" file.html; then rm "$f"; echo "Removed $f"; fi' \;
```

Comment: This looks good in the first place but it is error-prone. What if the term `1.jpg` is found somewhere else in the HTML but not in the img src attributes?

Comment: @hek2mgl: I think it is better now.

Comment: Better - yes, but still not stable. The solution using an HTML parser is the way to go. Like I said, the find usage basically looks better than the other bash solution but everytime you try to parse HTML with regexes or patterns you'll end up with an unstable solution.

Comment: @hek2mgl: it is the OP who decides. But, generally, I agree with you.

Comment: You would do well to take @hek2mgl advice and counsel. Nobody expects your to have a 100% perfect solution the first time, but when potential problems are pointed out, you will want to address them. This insures that answers on SO are reliable and not prone to cause havoc if someone a year from now decides to test it. I too like your solution, with a bit of minimal work, you can improve upon it.

Comment: Thank you for your coding here but going by the advice of using a HTML parser for stability is the advice that im going to take. Thank you again though

Comment: @David C. Rankin: I appreciate your thoughts. I actually have no problem accepting any kind of feedback, incuding criticism. Regarding the question itself, as you could have probably already noticed, the solutions are divided into 2 big domains: using a fully featured html interpreter or relying on some regex parsing of the html file. It is only the OP who knows what he really needs. Thanks once again.

Comment: @user1796216: I'm glad you've found an appropriate solution for your problem!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this. One is to fill an array with all the jpg files in the directory, then selectively delete the jpg files not found in the html file.

**Note:** the actual delete of files is commented out, you can confirm operations before enabling the actual delete. Currently, the script just prints what is saved and what is deleted:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $1 ] && {
    printf "error: insufficient input. usage:  %s path/to/file.html\n" ${0##*/}
    exit 1
}

[ -r "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: invalid filename '%s'. usage:  %s path/to/file.html\n" "$1" ${0##*/}
    exit 1
}

fname=${1##*/}  ## split filename/path
fpath=${1%/*}

[ "$fname" = "$fpath" ] && fpath="./"

jpgarray=( ${fpath}/*.jpg )                 ## read jpg files in directory

for i in ${jpgarray[@]}; do
    tmp=${i##*/}
    if grep "$tmp" "$1" >/dev/null; then
        printf "    file: %s exists in %s -- don't delete\n" "$i" "$1"
    else
        printf "    file: %s does NOT exist in %s -- deleting\n" "$i" "$1"
        # rm "${fpath}/${fname}"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

**jpg Files in Dir**

```
$ ls -1 dat/*.jpg
dat/01.jpg
dat/02.jpg
dat/03.jpg
dat/04.jpg
dat/05.jpg
dat/06.jpg
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/jpgnames.html
<img src="01.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1080" />
<img src="02.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1080" />
<img src="03.jpg" alt="" width="1920" height="1080" />
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash findjpg.sh dat/jpgnames.html
    file: dat/01.jpg exists in dat/jpgnames.html -- don't delete
    file: dat/02.jpg exists in dat/jpgnames.html -- don't delete
    file: dat/03.jpg exists in dat/jpgnames.html -- don't delete
    file: dat/04.jpg does NOT exist in dat/jpgnames.html -- deleting
    file: dat/05.jpg does NOT exist in dat/jpgnames.html -- deleting
    file: dat/06.jpg does NOT exist in dat/jpgnames.html -- deleting
```

Comment: Another downvote by someone who lacks the integrity to leave a comment to back it up and provide discourse for learning.

Comment: I did not down-voted but your answer is even more problematic than [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31038014/171318) - while being much more complicated. I don't get [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037777/bash-delete-type-of-file-thats-not-listed-within-a-html-file/31038014?noredirect=1#comment50101875_31038014) there and I don't get your intention behind this answer.

Comment: I fixed the problematic parts. Funny what seems the simple way at first doesn't always work out that way.

Comment: Thank you for your time and coding on this, BeautifulSoup made the task a lot easier and robust.

Answer (score -1):

This script only work if you only have 1 web page to check, there are more efficient scripts in terms of syntax but I think this is easier to understand for beginners:

```
#!/bin/bash
## loop through all the files in the image folder
for FILENAME in /path/to/image/folder/*; do

    # for each file, check (case insensitive) if it exists in your web page
    if grep -qi $(basename "$FILENAME") /path/to/webpage.html
    then
        # image file found in webpage
        echo "$FILENAME found, not deleting"
    else
        # image file not found in webpage
        echo "$FILENAME found, moving to trash"
        mv "$FILENAME" /path/to/trash/folder
    fi
done
```

It also moves files to a trash folder, just in case you need to recover them!!

Comment: Please try: `for FILENAME in /path/to/image/folder; do echo "$FILENAME" ; done`

Comment: You should *not* 1.) iterate over the results of a glob expression using `for var in ` 2.) parse HTML with regexes or patterns.. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time and coding but have opted for BeautifulSoup as the solution as it seems robust. However, I'll be taking your idea of moving stuff to trash, that never occurred to me.